# probability: picking an enzymatic pathway from a genome

Tags: probability

I have a genome (bag of marbles) that has 30,000 genes (marbles) in it.

I will be copying a single gene out of the genome (picking with replacement).

I will be copying 12 or 16 or 20 total genes in a round.

I am interested in calculating the probability that I copy 5 particular genes (ABCDE) in a batch of 12 (or 16 or 20).
In our genome, these 5 genes appear once each-- i.e the bag of 30,000 marbles has a single A, a single B, etc.

The order doesn't matter, nor do double or more picks  i.e

A B C D E x x x x x x x
E E E A x x D x B C x x

are both winners

How do I calculate the probability that I get all 5 genes at least once in a round of 12 or 16 or 20?

Please let me know if you need any clarification for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Let it be that there are $m$ genes. Let $p_{n,k}$ denote the probability
that $k$ selected genes show up in a round of $n$.

$$p_{n,k}=\frac{k}{m}\times p_{n-1,k-1}+\left(1-\frac{k}{m}\right)\times p_{n-1,k}$$

If I understand you well then you are interested in $p_{12,5}$, $p_{16,5}$
and $p_{20,5}$ in case $m=30,000$. This gives you a way to find it by recursion (quite a job, I think).